# join two column on a single table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with geographical info for routing. each route has a source info and destination info and I can understand the city of source and destination with a predefined function.
each route has a unique id named **code** and i want to create a table that shows source city and destination city beside each other.

I think it can be done with an inner join but I'm not familiar with SQL and this code not working for me.

anyone can help me?

```
select src.code , city1, city2 from 
(select data.code , provinces.name as city1 from data, provinces where st_within(st_geomfromwkb(data.src), provinces.geom)) as src
inner join (select select data.code , provinces.name as city2 from data, provinces where st_within(st_geomfromwkb(data.dst), provinces.geom)) as dst
on src.code = dst.code
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrongly repeated select in second subquery as (as a suggestion) you should not use obsolete join syntax based on where and table names comma separated

```
    select src.code 
        , src.city1
        , dst.city2 
    from (
        select data.code 
        , provinces.name as city1 
        from data
        INNER JOIN  provinces  ON  st_within(st_geomfromwkb(data.src), provinces.geom)
    )  src
    inner join (
         select data.code 
        , provinces.name as city2 
        from data
        INNER JOIN  provinces  ON st_within(st_geomfromwkb(data.dst), provinces.geom)
    )  dst on src.code = dst.code
```

Comment: Thank you, it works correctly now. but because of huge output how can I count all types of output based on city1 and city2?
I want to use count(*) group by city1 and city2